# Linq to entity timing problem

Tags: linq-to-entities

I created a data model that has some views from my database as entities,when I create a linq statment that has part of this view's entities ,the time processor take to execute the linq statment is very long..
can anyone help?

Comment: We need more details. Can you give us the LINQ query? Can we see the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to map the view as a is a table in the entity model
then the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

this query was working by very short time but before adding the views in the model
but after adding views it takes more that 10 minutes to be executed
          var roles=(from r in db.SystemObjectSet
                     where r.ObjectsTypes.ObjectType.Equals("Role")
                     select r
                         ).ToList();